# How to count the frequency for items in a prepared query?

Tags: php

I have a prepared query with the following result:

```
12
12
12
14
14
14
14
14
11
11
2
2
2
```

I simply want to return the number and its frequency:

```
12 3
14 5
11 2
2  3
```

My code is as follows:

```
  $count =0;
     while($DNB -> fetch())
      {
    //  echo "<br/>";
       $nomatch = 0;
       if($count ==0)
        {
          array_push($array, array($postalcode ,1));
          // echo $array[0][1];

        }
        else
        {
         for($i = 0; $i < count($array);$i++)
          {
           if($array[$i][0] != $postalcode)
            {
              $nomatch ++;
              if($nomatch == count($array) -1)
                {
                 array_push($array, array($postalcode ,1));
                 //echo $array[$i][1];
                 }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                  $array[$i][1]++;
                 }

                 }
                  }
                    $count = $count +1;
                 }



I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
```

Comment: array_count_values()

Comment: I do not get the right counts for each value.

Comment: You don't have any file access in your code as far as I can see.

Comment: I am sorry. This is not a file. It is prepared statement. I am fetching values from the prepared query.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "SELECT id, COUNT (*) FROM table GROUP BY id" as the initial sql query.